# PHPexcel header in Laravel

Tags: php, header, laravel-4, phpexcel, xlsx

I'm practice phpExcel in Laravel 4. The following code is based on [this phpExcel exercise](https://github.com/cystbear/PHPExcel/blob/master/Tests/01simple-download-xls.php). It works fine outside the Laravel. Since I only modified some necessary code to match with installing path, so I believe there are many Laravel user will face same issue if they using phpExcel. I do believe some expert do solved this already and hope they could give me a help.

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
ob_clean();
flush();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('d:/l4/test/01simple.xlsx');
ob_end();
exit;
```

However, I get this error message when I put the code in View:

> Excel cannot open the file 01simple.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid .

I Googled a lots and tried several options, but so far no luck. I've seen a similar question where someone solved this by adding `ob_clean()` and `flush()` just under header, but this does not work in Laravel.

I have MS excel 2010 and the downloaded file can be opened manually. I'm using WAMP (php 5.4), and tested with both Firefox and IE.
Here are complete code in View:

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
$pRoot=dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/vendor';
require_once $pRoot.'/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                         ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                         ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test  Document")
                         ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                         ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                         ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                         ->setCategory("Test result file");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
        ->setCellValue('A5', 'TW');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)

//$file = "myfile.xlsx";
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
ob_clean();
flush();
//readfile($file);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('d:/l4/test/01simple.xlsx');
ob_end();
exit;
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading the file and opening it in a text editor, to see what it actually contains?

Comment: @Boaz The file can be open by MS excel 2010 flawless, I do using sublime to open it but it is a binary and nothing I could tell if some where is wrong. thanks

Comment: Can you show us your view code..

Comment: @ Anam call from controller: return View::make('simpleDownloadXlsx');

Answer (score 4):

first ：

```
"phpexcel/phpexcel": "dev-master"
```

put the line above in ur composer.json's require option of Laravel . Then do the `composer update` , after that , u don't have to do the require_once job , Laravel had do that for u .

second :  are u request this excel generating action with Ajax ? if u do , i suggest u use the usuall way . cause the Ajax request method will affect the data format .

third : 
       do no use this : 
`$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');`to create 'Excel2007' writer object , u could only use this to create the 'Excel2005' writer object . use the method below :

```
   $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
   $objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);
   $objWriter->save($path);
```

wish u good luck !

Comment: here's a nice Document of PhpExcel . [link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Overview%20and%20Quickstart%20Guide) .